# How to Unescape HTML in XSS Simulation

Tags: html, xss

On my own web application, I'm trying to perform an XSS attack as part of a demonstration. I tried to do this by submitting some HTML (e. g. <h1>Click here</h1>) to a form that posts what gets submitted, but when I submitted the form, what gets posted is literally: <h1>Click here</h1>. If the HTML was not escaped, it would have displayed "Click here" in a large font. When I viewed the page source, it showed: <h1>Click here</h1> How can the HTML be unescaped when posting?

Comment: it depends on the coding you are using. The frontend or/and the backend could be sanitizing the inputs. without more information, nobody can tell.

Answer (score 0):

`var str = '<h1>Click Here</h1>'`
`var newStr = unescape(str)`

Append this newStr to html